# VM causing magit not to work

Tags: magit, tramp, git, exec-path

I have this error when I start emacs:

```
File error: Searching for program, no such file or directory, git
```

My Git is inside the VM in `/usr/bin/git`

How can I point emacs to it?

I'm using `tramp` and `plink` to communicate the VM and emacs.

I tried leaving in the `.emacs` file

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/plink:asti@192.168.33.10:/usr/bin/")
```

But it didn't help.

I also tried to install Git into windows but then when I visit Git repositories in the VM, Git from windows doesn't have access to the remote FS. Specifically, I press `M-x magit`, and emacs says:

```
Git repository:<path to where I am>
```

Then I press `enter`

Then it says:

```
 Create repository in /plink:asti@192.168.33.10:<path to where I am>
```

Whether I press Y or N, it doesn't help me.

Does anyone have any suggestions? How do I configure Magit to use the git binary on the remote machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Tramp doesn't use `exec-path`, it uses `tramp-remote-path`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-programs.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `magit-git-executable` can be customized. Its documentation:

> magit-git-executable is a variable defined in ‘magit-git.el’. Its
>   value is "git"
>
> Documentation: The Git executable used by Magit.

So, you should be able to set it to something like `asti@192.168.33.10/usr/bin/git`:

```
(setq magit-git-executable "asti@192.168.33.10/usr/bin/git")
```

I don't have a VM handy to test this with, but that should do it. You might run into problems where Emacs passes fully-qualified paths to git, but that might cause problems with git.

Comment: Sorry. I doesn't work.
It makes it even worse. Now emacs throws error all the time and even `C-x C-f` doesn't work and instead I get `Error in post-command-hood (magit-auto-revert-mode-check-buffers) : (file-error "Seaching for program" "no such file or directory" "/asti@192.168.33.10:/usr/bin/git"`

Comment: Can you try it without an opening slash? So `"asti@192.168.33.10:/usr/bin/git"`, not `"/asti@192.168.33.10:/usr/bin/git"`.

Comment: Hi zck. I tried, it didn't work either.
It still asks me `git repository: <my current dir>`... Basically, same as before.